# Add a parameter to a WPF custom control based on ITypeEditor?

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, xceed

`C#`, `WPF`, `xceed PropertyGrid`. I am using a custom control to provide a browse button in a `PropertyGrid`. There are variations in use case (e.g. most obviously browsing for a folder vs file), and creating separate editors for those cases would not be very DRY. Ideally I would like to introduce a parameter, but I am not sure how to pass that to the control. Is there a reasonably simple way to achieve this?

To me the most elegant solution would seem to be able to pass it an enum (for 'mode'), but if I could get the property that the editor is attached to (i.e. `ProjectFolder` in the following example) then that would also serve the purpose.

```
public partial class PropertyGridFilePicker : ITypeEditor
{
    string rtn = "";
    public PropertyGridFilePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(PropertyGridFilePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public FrameworkElement ResolveEditor(PropertyItem propertyItem)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding("Value");
        binding.Source = propertyItem;
        binding.Mode = propertyItem.IsReadOnly ? BindingMode.OneWay : BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
        return this;
    }

    private void PickFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == true && fd.CheckFileExists)
        {
            Value = fd.FileName;
            Value = rtn;
        }
    }
}
```

It is used like this:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyControls.PropertyGridFilePicker), typeof(MyControls.PropertyGridFilePicker))]
public string ProjectFolder { get; set; } = "";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given here:

[Possible to call the constructor of a WPF type editor (inheriting from ITypeEditor)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426819/possible-to-call-the-constructor-of-a-wpf-type-editor-inheriting-from-itypeedit)

Although posted as a different question, this related to the same problem. I asked for clarification on the Dependency Injection solution proposed in the other answer given here since I didn't understand how this could work. And it seems it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the most elegant way is by IoC. Dependency injection superceeds normal instancing.

Because if you later wish to introduce another type of folder handling or editor you just inject a new concrete instead of designing a instance of FrameworkElement. All you have to do is extend the existing functionality of FrameworkElement.

I won't write your code for you, but I will explain myself a bit better.

IoC is inversion of control, I personally, consider it part of the last step of the SOLID principles. Dependency Inversion.

You have to pass an abstraction. I recommend using an interface, instead of an abstract, to be honest, I don't think abstracts are really following the spirit of the dependency injection pattern. But meh, I don't see why not.

The concept is, that resolving the editor for example, should be done in an instance, that was created outside your FrameWorkElement class, and then passed into the constructor of your PropertyGridFilePicker.

You could also take a page from the SOLID principles and use the single responsibility pattern, meaning that a class should only ever have 1 responsibility. And you could argue that resolving the type editor based on a parameter det that otherwise doesn't effect the class, is a violation of this principle.

I would make it all interface dependent and pass in the required input likely from a controller, to concrete implementations that contain the resolving logic for editors, perhaps even the resolving logic for your value property and your source property.

This would allow you to pass 2 contrete instance into a single contrete that you then pass to the PropertyGridFilePicker class, and it creates it's bindings etc, from the contrete instance, of your "IResolveEditor" or whatever you want to call the interface, and configures the specific conctrete model of type "PropertyGridFilePicker", in this instance.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about IoC to be able to implement that without some specifics. As a fairly simple solution, can I get a reference to the property that the editor is applied to?

Comment: I have updated my answer, The specifics are not required to be followed, but I am trying to give a bit more of a hint to how it could be done. But short of actually writing the code for you, I wouldn't know how to explain this better ::)

Comment: If I can access the constructor of PropertyGridFilePicker and pass it a parameter then I think that would solve my problem. But I don't know how to do this. I am not explicitly instantiating an instance of PropertyGridFilePicker - I just decorate a property with it. (This is pretty much the same question that somebody was asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577901/c-sharp-uitypeeditor-with-parameter)  but the answer given proposed a different solution so I am none the wiser).

Comment: And someone says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456738/how-do-i-pass-an-argument-to-a-class-that-inherits-uitypeeditor) on a very similar issue, that _"Since you don't create the instance of your own UITypeEditor derivative, you have no control over what arguments are passed to the constructor"_.